global helmfile and multiple environments
I have on "big" helmfile which adresses two other sub-helmfile :
helmfiles:
  - path: ./helmfiles/system/helmfile.yaml
  - path: ./helmfiles/services/helmfile.yaml

In each sub-helmfile, there are many environments
system/helmfile.yaml:
environments:
  dev:...
  val:...
  prod:...

services/helmfile.yaml:
environments:
  azure:...
  onprem:...
  local:...

Is it possible to define "global" environment in the "global" helmfile in order to use each sub-helmfiles environments ?
Examples
global environments:

"env1" = system environment "dev" + service environment "local"
"env2" = system environment "dev" + service environment "onprem"
etc.

